# Google Ads not showing in div?

Tags: php, javascript, html, adsense

Hey, i don't understand why, but i have an ad box below the lightbulb on the page (view the source) and I don't see anything. I understand google take about 10 minutes to process ads and show things, but i have tried this for about a day using multiple test ad boxes but nothing seems to work.

tl;dr- I dont know how to use javascript and i can't figure out whats wrong on my ads

It should be in the information box below the lightbulb.

http://atomicpool.com/play.php?id=1

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Google is giving you a `400 Bad Request` when trying to load the ad itself.

Answer (score 0):

about javascript...here you have to just copy-paste ads code which is given by google.....
and its run properly...
and you have to configure size of div as google ads require...

Comment: I copy / pasted it fine. I'm a programmer.